# c++ program to insert word in character array

Tags: c++, arrays, insert, char

Hi I am having slight problem with inserting a word in a char array. The number of words are correct in output but the characters are showing wrong. I will attach the code I am doing please find the problem.
In the problem I have asked the user to input a main char array (`marr`) and a word to be inserted (`sarr`) and an index where it is to be inserted (`index`).

```
using namespace std;    
int main()    
{
    char marr[100], sarr[10], narr[200];
    int index;

    cout << "Enter main array data:" << endl;
    cin.getline(marr, 100);

    int mlen = strlen(marr);

    cout << "Enter word to be inserted:" << endl;
    cin.getline(sarr, 10);

    cout << "Enter index where word is to be inserted:" << endl;
    cin >> index;

    int slen = strlen(sarr);

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)     //filing new array upto index value of main array
    {
        narr[i] = marr[i];
    }

    int ilen = index + slen;
    for (int i = index; i < ilen; i++)        //filing inserted array
    {
        for (int j =0; j < slen; j++)
        {
            narr[i] = sarr[j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=ilen;i<mlen+slen;i++)     //filing left portion of main array in new array
    {
        for(int j=index;j<mlen;j++)
        {
            narr[i]=marr[j];
        }
    }
    narr[mlen+slen]='\0';

    cout<<"New Array: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<mlen+slen;i++)
    {
        cout<<narr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `std::string`?

Comment: I haven't learned about it and most importantly i want to solve this without using in built functions.It's very easy using in built functions.I want to solve without in built functions.

Comment: @LaibaAbid `std::string` is a **class**, not a function

Comment: ohh ok but can't you point out the mistake in this.I want to do it like this.please find out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part:

```
for (int i = index; i < ilen; i++)        //filing inserted array
{
    for (int j =0; j < slen; j++)
    {
        narr[i] = sarr[j];
    }
}
```

You just keep rewrite `narr[i]` with different characters so the statement would be equal to `narr[i] = sarr[slen - 1];`, which is not the purpose here.

What you should do is replace the inner loop with `narr[i] = sarr[i - index];`.

So it will be:

```
for (int i = index; i < ilen; i++)
{
    narr[i] = sarr[i - index];
}
```

In the same way change:

```
for(int i=ilen;i<mlen+slen;i++)     //filing left portion of main array in new array
{
    for(int j=index;j<mlen;j++)
    {
        narr[i]=marr[j];
    }
}
```

//Also use `mlen` not `mlen+slen` because you write to the end of `marr`.

To:

```
for(int i = ilen; i < mlen; i++)
{
    narr[i] = marr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters before this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
```

you have to check that `index` is not greater than `mlen`. Otherwise the loop can store invalid characters in the result array.

This statement

```
int slen = strlen(sarr);
```

is redundant. You always can determine the end of the string by the present zero-terminated character.

The subsequent nested loops are wrong. For example the copy of the array `sarr` in this loop

```
    for (int j =0; j < slen; j++)

    {

        narr[i] = sarr[j];

    }
```

are performed `slen` times.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    char marr[100], sarr[10], narr[200];

    size_t index;

    std::cout << "Enter main array data: ";

    std::cin.getline( marr, sizeof( marr ) );

    size_t mlen = std::strlen( marr );

    std::cout << "Enter word to be inserted: ";

    std::cin.getline( sarr, sizeof( sarr) );

    std::cout << "Enter index where word is to be inserted: ";

    std::cin >> index;  

    index = mlen < index ? mlen : index;

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < index; i++ ) narr[i] = marr[i];

    for ( size_t j = 0; sarr[j] != '\0'; j++, i++ ) narr[i] = sarr[j];

    for ( size_t j = index; j < mlen + 1; j++, i++ ) narr[i] = marr[j];

    std::cout<<"New Array: ";

    for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ ) std::cout << narr[j];
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter main array data: Hello Laiba Abid
Enter word to be inserted: mr. 
Enter index where word is to be inserted: 6
New Array: Hello mr. Laiba Abid
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is found in your double for-loops; By using a double for-loop, you keep overwriting the same letter in your array. (to see what I mean just add a cout << narr << "+" << sarr << endl;  in your code and you can see beautifully what I mean).

There is a fix available:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = index; i < ilen; i++)        //filing inserted array
{
    narr[i] = sarr[j];
    j++;
}
```

Declare a j outside your for-loop and just add one every time you loop through it. That fixes the insert of a new word.

To fix the end of your string:
(because you get the last letter of your original string as many times as the word is long)

```
j = index;
for(int i=ilen;i<mlen+slen;i++)     //filing left portion of main array in new array
{
    narr[i] = marr[j];
    j++;
}
```

Again we declare a variable outside of the for-loop and update it within. Now the variable can't be 0 because then you'll get the beginning of your original string, therefor set j = index

I hope this has helped you

Comment: Thank you so much.My code is now running perfectly.